# Will hand-written or using adobe acrobat reader or Advanced Micro Solutions software IRS Tax Forms correctly scan when mailed?

Tags: irs, form-1099, tax-forms

> https://www.sapling.com/8735031/do-1099-forms-typed
>
> https://www.bluesummitsupplies.com/blogs/tax-resources/can-you-handwrite-a-1099

There are websites that say hand-writing an IRS tax form from the order page on the irs.gov website will not scan, and you have to use special font and type the form.

I have no idea how to type on a printed form without a scanner using a type-writer. I also cannot find a type-writer.

Is there something special accountants do when creating IRS non e-filed forms such as special ink or a typer-writer?

Can a lay-person download IRS tax forms creation software, print out the results after buying from https://www.1099-etc.com/software/w2-and-1099-forms-filer/, and mail to IRS without future problems?

Will hand-written or using adobe acrobat reader filled out IRS Tax Forms correctly scan when mailed?

Comment: People may be misunderstanding -- it should be noted clearly that you are asking about filing a *1099 form* (reporting another person's income), not filing your *return* (reporting your own income). There is not an official fillable 1099 form that can be filed with the IRS. The downloadable 1099 forms say: "The official printed version of Copy A of this IRS form is scannable, but the online version of it, printed from this website, is not. Do not print and file copy A downloaded from this website; a penalty may be imposed for filing with the IRS information return forms that can’t be scanned."

Comment: Or, if you are actually interested in filing your tax return, not a 1099, then you have included some links that aren't pertinent. Either way, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Acrobat Reader software to fill the forms. See [the IRS instructions here](https://www.irs.gov/help/downloading-and-printing). You don't need a typewriter.

You can legally submit a handwritten return, but it will likely require manual processing. This is prone to errors, and may significantly delay the processing. It may also lead to a more detailed examination: since it's being manually processed already there's not much of incremental effort to have a Revenue Agent to look at it.

---

Thanks for @nanoman's callout about 1099: These forms are much more sensitive. You should not print them on your own, and instead use the official printed form you can [get from the IRS for free](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/online-ordering-for-information-returns-and-employer-returns) or from various providers (like your local office supplies store, maybe).